# SQL syntax error when updating value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update values in a database but only get this error. The database connects with no error, but with trying to update values it breaks. Here is a picture of the browser error and the update.php

[image]

```
<?php

$speed = $_GET["speed"];
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lng = $_GET["lng"];
$currentTime = time();

echo $speed . "<br>";
echo $lat . "<br>";
echo $lng . "<br>";

include "db_connect.php";

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "UPDATE where-am-I SET time='$currentTime' WHERE id=1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: It's quite possibly the fact that you have hyphens in your column names. This is bad 
practice. It's a common standard to use underscores. But try enclosing the column name in back ticks ```UPDATE `where-am-I` SET time='$currentTime' WHERE id=1```

Comment: Please don't post images of code and error messages. That error message is all but illegible to anyone who's eyes are less than perfect.

Comment: A possible cause might be worth checking that you have time column as DATETIME while passing an integer value in the SQL (I suspect because you wrap the value with quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (and MariaDB) allow only 0-9, a-z, A-Z, $ and _ in unquoted object names. (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

You can use hyphens if you wrap the name in backticks

For example

```
SELECT * FROM `table-name-with-hyphens`
```

I'd recommend you refrain from using hyphens and other special characters in your object names to avoid other possible conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, changing the name to "where_am_I" fixed it.